# How can I see the services and the characteristics of the ble module I'm connected to?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making an Android app that is supposed to connect to a BLE-module and should be able to read it's services and characteristics. My app is based on the code of Accent Systems' ["iBKS Hello World"](https://accent-systems.com/support/developers/ibks-hello-world/) application.

I am not using iBeacons, but a different kind of BLE-module. But when I connect to it, the app is not showing a list of services and characteristics as the code indicates should happen.

Can anyone help me fix this problem? Please let me know!

My code:

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//DEFINE VARS
String TAG = "ScanActivity";

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
BluetoothLeScanner scanner;
ScanSettings scanSettings;


private List<String> scannedDeivcesList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//DEFINE LAYOUT
ListView devicesList;

//THIS METHOD RUNS ON APP LAUNCH
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    //Define listview in layout
    devicesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.devicesList);
    //Setup list on device click listener
    setupListClickListener();

    //Initialize de devices list
    scannedDeivcesList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Initialize the list adapter for the listview with params: Context / Layout file / TextView ID in layout file / Devices list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, scannedDeivcesList);

    //Set the adapter to the listview
    devicesList.setAdapter(adapter);


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Scan for modules");

    s.setSpan(new com.accent_systems.ibkshelloworld.TypefaceSpan(this, "Khand-Bold.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#3a3c3e")), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    setTitle(s);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    //init Bluetooth adapter
    initBT();
    //Start scan of bluetooth devices
    startLeScan(true);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    startLeScan(false);
}

private void initBT(){
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =  (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    //Create the scan settings
    ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    //Set scan latency mode. Lower latency, faster device detection/more battery and resources consumption
    scanSettingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
    //Wrap settings together and save on a settings var (declared globally).
    scanSettings = scanSettingsBuilder.build();
    //Get the BLE scanner from the BT adapter (var declared globally)
    scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
}

private void startLeScan(boolean endis) {
    if (endis) {
        //********************
        //START THE BLE SCAN
        //********************
        //Scanning parameters FILTER / SETTINGS / RESULT CALLBACK. Filter are used to define a particular
        //device to scan for. The Callback is defined above as a method.
        scanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, mScanCallback);
    }else{
        //Stop scan
        scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    }
}


private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

        //Here all the detected BLE devices will be received . "result" contains the device
        //address and name as a BLEPeripheral, the advertising content as a ScanRecord, the Rx RSSI
        //and the timestamp when received. Type result.get... to see all the available methods you can call.

        //Convert advertising bytes to string for a easier parsing. GetBytes may return a NullPointerException. Treat it right(try/catch).
        String advertisingString = byteArrayToHex(result.getScanRecord().getBytes());
        //Print the advertising String in the LOG with other device info (ADDRESS - RSSI - ADVERTISING - NAME)
        Log.i(TAG, result.getDevice().getAddress()+" - RSSI: "+result.getRssi()+"\t - "+advertisingString+" - "+result.getDevice().getName());

        //Check if scanned device is already in the list by mac address
        boolean contains = false;
        for(int i=0; i<scannedDeivcesList.size(); i++){
            if(scannedDeivcesList.get(i).contains(result.getDevice().getAddress())){
                //Device already added
                contains = true;
                //Replace the device with updated values in that position
                scannedDeivcesList.set(i, result.getRssi()+"  "+result.getDevice().getName()+ "\n       ("+result.getDevice().getAddress()+")");
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!contains){
            //Scanned device not found in the list. NEW => add to list
            scannedDeivcesList.add(result.getRssi()+"  "+result.getDevice().getName()+ "\n       ("+result.getDevice().getAddress()+")");
        }

        //After modify the list, notify the adapter that changes have been made so it updates the UI.
        //UI changes must be done in the main thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
};

//Method to convert a byte array to a HEX. string.
private String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
    for(byte b: a)
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    return sb.toString();
}

void setupListClickListener(){
    devicesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Stop the scan
            Log.i(TAG, "SCAN STOPPED");
            scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

            //Get the string from the item clicked
            String fullString = scannedDeivcesList.get(position);
            //Get only the address from the previous string. Substring from '(' to ')'
            String address = fullString.substring(fullString.indexOf("(")+1, fullString.indexOf(")"));
            //Get BLE device with address
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            //******************************
            //START CONNECTION WITH DEVICE AND DECLARE GATT
            //******************************
            Log.i(TAG,"*************************************************");
            Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTION STARTED TO DEVICE "+address);
            Log.i(TAG,"*************************************************");

            //ConnectGatt parameters are CONTEXT / AUTOCONNECT to connect the next time it is scanned / GATT CALLBACK to receive GATT notifications and data
            // Note: On Samsung devices, the connection must be done on main thread
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(ScanActivity.this, false, mGattCallback);

            /*
            There is also another simplest way to connect to a device. If you already stored
            the device in a list (List<BluetoothDevice>) you can retrieve it directly and
            connect to it:
            mBluetoothGatt = mList.get(position).connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, mGattCallback);
             */
        }
    });
}

//Connection callback
BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
        new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    //Device connected, start discovering services
                    Log.i(TAG, "DEVICE CONNECTED. DISCOVERING SERVICES...");
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    //Device disconnected
                    Log.i(TAG, "DEVICE DISCONNECTED");
                }
            }

            // On discover services method
            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    //Services discovered successfully. Start parsing services and characteristics
                    Log.i(TAG, "SERVICES DISCOVERED. PARSING...");
                    displayGattServices(gatt.getServices());
                } else {
                    //Failed to discover services
                    Log.i(TAG, "FAILED TO DISCOVER SERVICES");
                }
            }

            //When reading a characteristic, here you receive the task result and the value
            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    //READ WAS SUCCESSFUL
                    Log.i(TAG, "ON CHARACTERISTIC READ SUCCESSFUL");
                    //Read characteristic value like:
                    //characteristic.getValue();
                    //Which it returns a byte array. Convert it to HEX. string.
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "ERROR READING CHARACTERISTIC");
                }
            }

            //When writing, here you can check whether the task was completed successfully or not
            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "ON CHARACTERISTIC WRITE SUCCESSFUL");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "ERROR WRITING CHARACTERISTIC");
                }
            }

            //In this method you can read the new values from a received notification
            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                Log.i(TAG, "NEW NOTIFICATION RECEIVED");
                //New notification received. Check the characteristic it comes from and parse to string
                /*if(characteristic.getUuid().toString().contains("0000fff3")){
                    characteristic.getValue();
                }*/
            }

            //RSSI values from the connection with the remote device are received here
            @Override
            public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
                Log.i(TAG, "NEW RSSI VALUE RECEIVED");
                //Read remote RSSI like: mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
                //Here you get the gatt table where the rssi comes from, the rssi value and the
                //status of the task.
            }
        };

//Method which parses all services and characteristics from the GATT table.
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    //Check if there is any gatt services. If not, return.
    if (gattServices == null) return;

    // Loop through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SERVICE FOUND: "+gattService.getUuid().toString());
        //Loop through available characteristics for each service
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "  CHAR. FOUND: "+gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString());
        }
    }

    //****************************************
    // CONNECTION PROCESS FINISHED!
    //****************************************
    Log.i(TAG, "*************************************");
    Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTION COMPLETED SUCCESFULLY");
    Log.i(TAG, "*************************************");

}
```

}

Comment: _"...a different kind of BLE-module...is not showing a list of services and characteristics"_ We know even less about the module than you do. :) So, what's the problem? The services and characteristics are not documented anywhere? What's the mystery module? There are a few words about interfacing with a GATT server in [Not receiving data from BLE device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779643/not-receiving-data-from-ble-device/32955582#32955582) but there are probably some better guidance out there on the web.

Comment: It's a ble module from cypress with ez serial. If I connect to it using the nRF Connect app, I can see all its services and characteristics. When I connect to it with my app, it does not show me anything.

My problem is not with the BLE-module, it is with the code in my app. I know the BLE-module is working correctly.

Comment: Okay. Any relevant code should be in the question itself and not on an external site as external resources can become unavailable and then the question isn't clear anymore.

Comment: Okay, then I'll paste the code here. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You may find full description [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266823/1416374) short example. So you bring list of services after BLE connection and services request. Later you may request characteristics for every service. Main idea when you bring services one by one you have it UUID and reference. If you have know some service that you like to use you should know it before bring all services. And on collecting them save somewhere reference of service test every by known UUID. Later use this reference for bring characteristics and interconnection with device.